# Haskell - Problems in the Mandelbrot drawer

Tags: haskell, mandelbrot

So, as a beginner, I thought I would work on a horribly, awefully terrible version of the mandelbrot set project. In this pitiful case, the set is drawn with text (Shreik!) into a text file. Because I wanted some practice with some numerical coding, I have designed the worst complex number system in existance. I can't spot the problem in the code - the one that draws a band instead of a mandelbrot set. Here it is (don't look at it too long or you could die from over expossure to noob-ioactivity):

```
-- complex numbers, test for mandelbrot set

----------------- Complex Numbers

data C = Complex Float Float -- a + bi
    deriving Show

data Mandelbrot = Possible -- if thought to be in mandelbrot set
                | Not Integer -- this Integer is iterations before |z| > 2 in z=z^2+c
    deriving Show

complexReal :: C -> Float
complexReal (Complex n _) = n

complexImaginary :: C -> Float
complexImaginary (Complex _ n) = n

modulus :: C -> Float
modulus (Complex n m) = sqrt ((n^2) + (m^2))

argument :: C -> Float --returns in radians
argument (Complex m n)  | n < 0 && m < 0 = pi + (argument (Complex (0-m) (0-n)))
                        | m < 0 = (pi / 2) + (argument (Complex (0-m) n))
                        | n < 0 = ((3 * pi) / 2) + (argument (Complex m (0-n)))
                        | otherwise = atan (n / m)

multComplex :: C -> C -> C
multComplex (Complex m n) (Complex x y) = Complex ((m*x)-(n*y)) ((m*y)+(n*x))

addComplex :: C -> C -> C
addComplex (Complex m n) (Complex x y) = Complex (m + x) (m + y)

----------------- End Complex numbers

----------------- Mandelbrot

inMandelbrot :: C -> Mandelbrot
inMandelbrot c = inMandelbrotTest (Complex 0 0) c 0

--(z, c, i terations) with z=z^2+c, c is plotted on set map if z is bound
inMandelbrotTest :: C -> C -> Integer -> Mandelbrot 
inMandelbrotTest z c i  | (modulus z) > 2 = Not i -- too large
                        | i > 100 = Possible -- upper limit iterations
                        | otherwise = inMandelbrotTest (addComplex (multComplex z z) c) c (i+1)

possiblyInMandelbrot :: Mandelbrot -> Bool
possiblyInMandelbrot Possible = True
possiblyInMandelbrot _ = False

mandelbrotLine :: [C] -> String
mandelbrotLine [] = "\n"
mandelbrotLine (n:x) | possiblyInMandelbrot (inMandelbrot n) = "#" ++ mandelbrotLine x
mandelbrotLine (_:x) = " " ++ mandelbrotLine x

mandelbrotFeild :: [[C]] -> String
mandelbrotFeild [[]] = ""
mandelbrotFeild (n:x) = (mandelbrotLine n) ++ (mandelbrotFeild x)

-----------------End Mandelbrot

---------------- textual output

feildLine :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> [C] -- start R, end R, i, increment x
feildLine s e i x   | s > e = []
                    | otherwise = [(Complex s i)] ++ feildLine (s+x) e i x

feildGenerate :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> [[C]] -- start R, end R, start i, end i, increment x
feildGenerate sr er si ei x | si > ei = [[]]
                            | otherwise = [(feildLine sr er si x)] ++ (feildGenerate sr er (si+x) ei x)

l1 :: String
l1 = mandelbrotFeild (feildGenerate (-3) 3 (-3) 3 0.05)

---------------- End textual output

main = do
    writeFile "./mandelbrot.txt" (l1)
```

As you can see (or can't if you didn't look) there are some unused functions for my Complex numbers. Is there hope doctor?

**Summary**:
Why does this draw a band instead of the mandelbrot set?

Comment: So, what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: Why do you defame your code so much? Learning is about trying things out. Not knowing something or learning is nothing to be ashamed of.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use some existing library for complex numbers first, such as [the one in base](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Complex.html). This will help you focus on the Mandelbrot part and to avoid possible errors in your implementation of `Complex`. And the existing library also implements the standard numerical classes such as `Num` or `Fractional`, which makes expressions much more readable. Later you can try implementing your own version, if you wish. (Note: This question should perhaps rather belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .)

Comment: I know very well that the code is not *that* aweful. I was just trying to push the point that I know the code isn't perfect. I mean, look at the corrections given by MathematicalOrchid. Thanks all so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found your bug:

```
addComplex :: C -> C -> C
addComplex (Complex m n) (Complex x y) = Complex (m + x) (m + y)
```

It's really that simple. You have a trivial typo.

---

Some other suggestions:

- Use `Double` rather than `Float`. For this example, it seems to give visibly more accurate results.
- `[x] ++ y` is the same thing as `x : y`.
- It is traditional to write `x : xs` rather than `x : y`. This makes it clear that one is a list element, the other is a list.
- You can import `Data.Complex` to get complex-number arithmetic - but of course, you are writing this code for the purpose of learning, so that's fine.
- If you define `instance Num C where...`, then you would be able to write `z*z + c` rather than `addComplex (mulComplex z z) c`. It's prettier to read - if you know how to write instances yet...
- You can't spell "field". ;-)

Comment: I thought it would be a typo. and 'feild' was just easier to use seeing as I used it in the definition originally. (I will use search and replace.) Thank you so much - another set of eyes always helps. I thought about trying to define a (++) function for my complex numbers, and the only thing instances have been for me are headaches when trying to find == on custom data types!

Comment: Well, it was either going to be a bug in generating the coordinates, or a bug in the actual iteration. GHCi lets you quickly and easily check that the coordinates look OK, so...

Comment: therefore the iteration contained a problems!